# Twitter APIv2 Expansions Using Tweepy

Tags: python, tweepy, twitterapi-python

I have a pretty basic application which uses Tweepy's StreamingClient to stream tweets from a defined list of users. When one of them tweets, I have a couple conditions based on keywords to determine if I should alert myself. I want it to send me both the text of the tweet and the username of who sent it. I can do the former, but can figure out how to get the username.

From what I have seen I need to use expansions, but I'm a complete novice and don't know how I would integrate that into my code because the majority of the documentation for expansions is on the twitter API and I'm not sure how to apply that to my python code which uses tweepy.

Stripped down version of my code, currently just handling the tweet text is as follows ( I want to print user name in addition to tweet.text):

```
import tweepy
import json
import re
import logging


class MyListener(tweepy.StreamingClient):
    def on_tweet(self, tweet):
        keyword = ["xxxx", "yyyy","zzzz"]
        key_patterns = [r'\b%s\b' % re.escape(s.strip()) for s in keyword]
        key_there = re.compile('|'.join(key_patterns))
        if key_there.search(tweet.text):
            print(tweet.text)
       
        else:
            print("No Match")
        
        
    def on_error(self, status):
        print(status)
        return True
 
twitter_stream = MyListener("token")

twitter_stream.get_rules()
twitter_stream.filter()
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm a little late here, nevertheless, I shall be dropping an answer in case anybody finds it helpful in the future. To access User data in Twitter API V2, you need to pass `expansions = author_id` to the filter method. Now, you can use the `user_fields` parameter to pass your desired user fields. However, by default, `name`, `username` and `id` will be returned. Specify any other desired fields in a comma-separated list without spaces between commas and fields. (Refer https://docs.tweepy.org/en/stable/expansions_and_fields.html)

For the different user fields, refer https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-api/data-dictionary/object-model/user

You also need to change the `on_tweet` method to `on_data`. The data will be received as a json string, consisting of `data`, `includes`, and `matching_rules` fields
(Refer https://docs.tweepy.org/en/stable/streamingclient.html).

Your code will look like this:

```
import tweepy
import json
import re
import logging


class MyListener(tweepy.StreamingClient):
     def on_data(self, data):
        jsonData = json.loads(data)
        print(jsonData) #notice the different fields. 'username' comes with the key 'users' which itself comes in the 'includes' field.
        tweetText = jsonData['data']['text']
        username = jsonData['includes']['users']['username'] 
        print(username)
        keyword = ["xxxx", "yyyy","zzzz"]
        key_patterns = [r'\b%s\b' % re.escape(s.strip()) for s in keyword]
        key_there = re.compile('|'.join(key_patterns))
        if key_there.search(tweetText):
            print(tweetText)
       
        else:
            print("No Match")
        
        
    def on_error(self, status):
        print(status)
        return True
 
twitter_stream = MyListener("token")

twitter_stream.get_rules()
twitter_stream.filter(expansions = ['author_id'], user_fields = ["<required fields>"])
```

Answer (score 0):

`tweet` objects has a `user` atribute, and the `user` attribute has a `screen_name` attribute, this is the username.
You can get it this way:

```
class MyListener(tweepy.StreamingClient):
    def on_tweet(self, tweet):
        keyword = ["xxxx", "yyyy","zzzz"]
        key_patterns = [r'\b%s\b' % re.escape(s.strip()) for s in keyword]
        key_there = re.compile('|'.join(key_patterns))
        if key_there.search(tweet.text):
            print(tweet.text)
            print(tweet.user.screen_name)
       
        else:
            print("No Match")
```

Comment: I'll like it if you can describe how you set "twitter_stream" and "streaming_client". Thank you.

Comment: Hi - thanks for the response. I used something like that in the version that ran on the previous version of the API. But now in tweepy 4.6 which uses the twitter V2 API, the only attributes which I seem to be able to access are tweet ID and tweet text. there is documentation on the twitter API here that correlates with why I can only access those 2 by default https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-api/data-dictionary/using-fields-and-expansions  however the documentation seems geared toward using the API directly as opposed to tweepy